# Regarding abbreviations in chapter/section titles in a technical text

Tags: abbreviations, technical, initialisms

What is common practice regarding the use of abbreviations in chapter/section titles in a technical text? Is it encouraged? Should it be avoided? Is it preferable to include the full name of the term in question AND its abbreviation? Does it depend on how recently the term was defined in the text? Let's assume that the abbreviation in question is not necessarily very broadly known.

By the way, I happen to believe that the use of abbreviations in the title of the work itself (e.g. a scientific paper or a PhD thesis) is unacceptable (but please correct me if I'm wrong). Section titles seems to me to be a bit of a gray zone, however.

For instance, what is preferable out of the following alternatives?

> Section 1: The Streamline-Upwind Petrov-Galerkin method

or

> Section 1: The SUPG method

or

> Section 1: The Streamline-Upwind Petrov-Galerkin (SUPG) method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer depends on how common the initialism "SUPG" is among your audience. I would rank your above examples second, then third, then first, in order of decreasing audience familiarity. If it's as familiar as "LOL" is to the general public, don't bother spelling it out. At the other extreme, if your work *introduces* the method name or the initialism, use your first example as the section title. If you intend on coining and using the initialism, introduce it in the body with "The Streamline-Upwind Petrov-Galerkin (SUPG) method" rather than in the section title.